# How to unwrap part of a body to a single material

Tags: uv

I imported an FBX (from Character Creator 3) that had 8 textures associated with one mesh.  The FBX imports and looks great.

I want to look at the UV mapping for the "head" material to see how it is unwrapped. (I plan on wrapping the texture on another model).

Looking at the mesh in the outliner and property panel shows it has 8 materials.
Looking at the vertexes in the properties panel shows that is has only one UV map.

Selecting the mesh and selecting the "head" material and viewing the unwrap in the Texture view, shows the unwrap for all 8 materials simultaneously.

I can't select "just the head", as it appears to be fully part of the body.

I'm missing something that's probably obvious. How can I view and edit just one materials UV?

Answer (score 1):

OK. The obvious part I missed is that I need to just select the vertices. I still don't see how it has a single UV map that spans 8 different materials, but that doesn't actually matter for what I'm doing.